# Using Amelia (multiple imputation) output for analysis using functions other than linear regression

Tags: r, r-zelig

**Background** Use of the *Zelig* package on *Amelia* output for linear regression is well outlined in the [Amelia II documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Amelia/vignettes/amelia.pdf).

**Problem** Unfortunately, I am unable to find any documentation of how to use this output for other analysis. The problem seems to lie with how other packages see the Amelia output.

Since the *Zelig* package seems be able to treat all the imputations as one data set, I'd love to be able to use that single data set for manipulation with other packages (e.g., *dplyr*), but I'm unable to get a single data.frame out of the package.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this answers your question, but you can extract the imputed datasets using:

```
df <- a.out$imputations[[1]]
```

Which will assign the first imputed dataset to the data.frame df.